# Short(er) proof of `forall n k, (forall q, n <> q * 3) -> n + n <> k * 3`

Tags: coq

In a proof I need to show that "if *n* is not a multiple of three, then *n+n* is also not a multiple of three."  I think my proof is too long and not very elegant. Is there some prettier way of writing it?  With or without ssreflect? (I'm sure there is a oneliner in ssreflect :) ).

My proof does induction over `n` in steps of three.

```
Require Import Omega.
Lemma math_helper n: forall k, (forall q, n <> q * 3) ->  n + n <> k * 3.
  (* name the predicate Q and strengthen induction hypothesis *)
  pattern n; match goal with [ _:_ |- ?P ?n] => let X := fresh Q in remember P as X end.
  enough (Q n /\ Q (1+n) /\ Q (2+n)) by tauto.
  induction n; subst Q;
    [| destruct IHn as [IH1 [IH2 IH3]]];
    repeat split; simpl; intros; auto; try omega.
  intro C; assert (k>=2) by omega; do 2 (try destruct k); try omega.
  assert (n+n = k*3) by omega.
  apply (IH1 k); auto; intros q HH; eapply (H (1+q)); subst n; omega.
Qed.
```

Comment: Note the existence of https://codereview.stackexchange.com which may be particularly adequate for such questions (it isn't much used for Coq right now, but a question there won't be missed at least by those who follow the Coq tag across all Stack Exchange sites, using a filter such as this one https://stackexchange.com/filters/299857/questions-tagged-coq-on-stackexchange-sites).

Comment: Thanks for all the great answers - all with different interesting ideas, and all deserve the check mark! I have to somewhat arbitrarily pick Yves' second answer because it is so elementary, but the "gauss-divides" based ones are also great!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is an even simpler solution, just relying on division, and letting omega do the reasoning.

```
Lemma math_helper2 n : forall k, (forall q, n <> q * 3) ->  n + n <> k * 3.
Proof.
intros k kq A.
assert (k = 2 * (k / 2) + k mod 2) by (apply Nat.div_mod; omega).
assert (k mod 2 < 2) by (apply (Nat.mod_bound_pos k 2); omega).
apply (kq (k/2)); omega.
Qed.
```

Answer (score 6):

As it is often the case, the answer is an ssreflect one-liner:

```
From mathcomp Require Import ssreflect ssrbool ssrnat div.

Lemma math_helper n : 3 %| n.*2 -> 3 %| n.
Proof. by rewrite -muln2 Gauss_dvdl. Qed.
```

OK, I cheated a little bit, because I changed the statement of the theorem.  Here's a proof of what you actually asked for.

```
Lemma math_helper n k : (forall q, n <> q * 3) -> n + n <> k * 3.
Proof.
rewrite addnn -mul2n mulnC => h1 h2.
suff/dvdnP [q /h1]: 3 %| n by [].
by rewrite -(@Gauss_dvdl _ _ 2) //; apply/dvdnP; eauto.
Qed.
```

Comment: A refinement on Arthur's answer: `Lemma dvdnPN d m : (forall k, m <> k * d) <-> ~~ (d %| m).
    Proof. by split=> [H|/dvdnP H k P]; [apply/dvdnP; case|apply: H; exists k]. Qed.` and now you can do:

    `Lemma math_helper n : (forall q, n <> q * 3) -> forall k, n + n <> k * 3.
    Proof.
    by move/dvdnPN=> ?; apply/dvdnPN; rewrite addnn -muln2 Gauss_dvdl.
    Qed.`

Answer (score 5):

This can also be solved in vanilla Coq using Gauss's lemma from the standard library (so the following is merely a reformulation of what Arthur has already showed):

```
Require Import Coq.Numbers.Natural.Peano.NPeano.

Lemma math_helper n k : (forall q, n <> q * 3) -> n + n <> k * 3.
Proof.
  fold (Nat.double n); rewrite Nat.double_twice, (Nat.mul_comm k 3); intros H1 H2.
  assert (3 | 2 * n) as H3 by (rewrite H2; apply Nat.divide_factor_l).
  apply Nat.gauss in H3 as [x contra]; auto.
  apply (H1 _ contra).
Qed.
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is an answer without ssreflect.

You can replace your three-step induction by course-of-value induction using well_founded_induction and lt_wf, then you can make all numeric proofs using
omega.  You still have to handle the universally quantified negations by hand though.

```
Require Import Wellfounded Arith Omega.

Lemma math_helper n : forall k, (forall q, n <> q * 3) ->  n + n <> k * 3.
Proof.
induction n as [n' Ih] using (well_founded_ind lt_wf).
intros k pn' A; destruct (eq_nat_dec n' 0) as [n0 | nn0];[now intros; case (pn' 0); omega| ].
assert (cnd: n' - 3 < n') by omega.
apply (Ih _ cnd (k - 2));[intros q A'; apply (pn' (S q))|]; omega.
Qed.
```

Answer (score 2):

A refinement on Arthur's answer that I happen to like:

```
Lemma forall_negP T (P : T -> Prop) : (forall k, ~ P k) <-> ~ (exists k, P k).
Proof.
split; first by move=> H [w Hw]; apply: (H w).
by move=> H k Hk; apply: H; exists k.
Qed.

Lemma dvdnPN d m : (forall k, m <> k * d) <-> ~~ (d %| m).
Proof. by rewrite forall_negP; split=> /dvdnP. Qed.

Lemma math_helper n : (forall q, n <> q * 3) -> forall k, n + n <> k * 3.
Proof. by move/dvdnPN=> ?; apply/dvdnPN; rewrite addnn -muln2 Gauss_dvdl. Qed.
```

@AntonTrunov suggests:

```
Lemma math_helper n : (forall q, n <> q * 3) -> forall k, n + n <> k * 3.
Proof. by rewrite !dvdnPN addnn -muln2 Gauss_dvdl. Qed.
```

which is fairly nice!

Anyways, as Arthur pointed out, the OP should get rid of the lemma altogether by being more careful with their statements.

Comment: Does `by rewrite !dvdnPN addnn -muln2 Gauss_dvdl.` feel less elegant (as the proof of `math_helper`)?

Comment: I didn't realize that neither ssreflect nor stdlib have `forall_negP` as a lemma.

Comment: @AntonTrunov I think it is somewhere but I couldn't find it. The other proof looks indeed good too, I tend to forget about setoid rewriting!

Comment: Me neither :) `Search` and grep didn't help. The "closest" thing is [Classical_Pred_Type](https://coq.inria.fr/distrib/current/stdlib/Coq.Logic.Classical_Pred_Type.html) in stdlib.